# docker ps is empty after docker run

Tags: docker, openldap

I try to run an openldap container:

```
docker run -p 389:389 -p 636:636 --name my-test-container --detach osixia/openldap:1.3.0 LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD="admin"
```

returns a hash (container id I guess).

When I test:

```
docker ps
```

shows an empty list.

What am I missing? What should I check for?

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
docker ps
```

only shows **running** docker containers.

If you want to list **all** docker containers, exec

```
docker ps -a
```

If you want the container to run in background, just add `-d` to the run command.

If you want to start the container with an interactive shell, add `-it` to the run command.

Comment: OK great, thank you...but shouldn't the first command I mentioned also run openldap inside the container?

Comment: It will be stopped immediately, see my edit about running it interactively/in background

Comment: What about `docker run --help` or `docker ps --help`? If my answer helped you, I would appreciate you accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
docker logs my-test-container
```

to see what went wrong when pulling the service up

Comment: First I ran `docker ps -a` then I took the the `container id` or `contianer name` (last column). Then running `docker logs container-name` I found the issue in my Dockerfile. Good answer thanks.